# How to perform NTLM authentication in Rest Assured POST method?

Tags: java, rest-assured

Currently I'm trying to automate MS dynamics app which has a REST call but it requires NTLM authentication.

Currently I tried in the `.auth().ntlm()` method which is not working. Please help to solve this issue.

please see sample code below:

```
String certificatesTrustStorePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_181\\lib\\security\\cacerts";
         System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", certificatesTrustStorePath);
    String URL =baseURL;
    RestAssured.baseURI = URL;
    String Body=data;
    String NtlmUsername="";
    String Ntlmpassword="";
    String Ntlmdomain="AD";
    String Ntlmworkstation="";
    Headers headers;
    Header FirstHeader = new Header(header1,header1_value);
    headers = new Headers(FirstHeader);

    Response response1= RestAssured.given().auth().ntlm(NtlmUsername,Ntlmpassword,Ntlmdomain,Ntlmworkstation).config(RestAssured.config().sslConfig(
            new SSLConfig().relaxedHTTPSValidation())).headers(headers)
            .body(data).when()
            .post(resourceURL);
```

and the error message displayed was:

```
Dec 27, 2018 12:49:12 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestTargetAuthentication process
WARNING: NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))
```

Comment: Hi, show your sample code so that it is easier for others to understand your problem

Comment: @ycx sample code is given